# How to expand integer sequence into subscript operator in C++11?

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

Lets define inputs:

```
double values[2][2]...[2] N times
bool signs[N];
```

what I want to do is to write a template function for something like this:

```
auto result = values[signs[0]][signs[1]]...[signs[N - 1]];
```

Unfortunately without folding expressions of C++17 I can't implement that.

I'm sure I need to use `std::index_sequence<>` in some way:

```
template <std::size_t ... indices>
double get_value(const dimension_creator_t<sizeof...(indices)>& values, 
                 index_sequence<indices...>, bool (&signs)[sizeof...(indices)])
```

but not sure how to proceed. I can find code of `std::integer_sequence` online. `dimension_creator_t` is an alias for the type of `values`.

How can I implement the desired functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work, though I took some liberty by using `std::array`  instead. It's just a bit more convenient.

Each call to `value_getter<size,I>::get<T>` takes `std::array<T,2>` as argument and trims it based on `signs[I]` so we get `arr[signs[I]` of type T, which is again a nested array (if I != size) so we again call `value_getter<size,I>::get` with T as argument.

A helper `value_getter` struct to get trim down the nested arrays piece by piece.

```
template <std::size_t size, std::size_t I> struct value_getter {
template <typename T>
    static double& get(std::array<T,2>& arr, const std::array<bool, size>& signs) {
        return value_getter<size, I+1>::template get(arr[signs[I]], signs);
    }
};
```

Final base case that returns the reference to value.

```
template <std::size_t size> struct value_getter<size, size> {
    static template <typename T> double& get(T& arr, const std::array<bool, size>& signs) {
        return arr;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
 std::array< std::array< std::array< double, 2>, 2>, 2> values{};
 std::array<bool, 3> signs{};

 double v = value_getter<3,0>::template get(values, signs);
```

[Demo](http://cpp.sh/4kb6j)

<s>I was pondering on how to make it work with C array style though, the problem is how to represent the type `std::array<T,2>` in the `::get` function. It can be made to work by something like `std::add_pointer<T>` which should give `T*` from `T`.</s>

So it's actually much more simple for C style arrays.

Here `T` would signify the array itself. If we bypass some static error checking, T is basically unused as a type. Since we know `arr` of type T is an array (if `I != size`) then we can always call the `operator[]` on `arr`.

```
template <std::size_t size, std::size_t I> struct value_getter {
template <typename T>
    static double& get(T arr, bool *signs) {
        return value_getter<size, I+1>::template get(arr[signs[I]], signs);
    }
};
```

The base case is trivial again.

```
template <std::size_t size> struct value_getter<size, size> {
    static double& get(double& arr, bool * signs) {
        return arr;
    }
};
```

[Demo(C array)](http://cpp.sh/7l5p)